# yesod test - missing dependency yesod-test

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I was setting up a yesod scaffolded site using the `yesod init` command, and I named my project `yesodtry`. I proceeded to setup a scaffolded site using this command, which was given by `yesod init`:

```
cd yesodtry && cabal sandbox init && cabal install && yesod devel
```

Everything went smoothly, and I accessed the demo site at `127.0.0.1:3000`. Out of curiosity, I tried to try the `yesod test` command. Here's the output I got:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring yesodtry-0.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
hspec -any, yesod-test ==1.2.*
```

Seeing how the `yesodtry.cabal` file has a `test` section, I tried executing `cabal build test`, and this is the output:

```
cabal: Cannot build the test suite 'test' because test suites are not enabled.
Run configure with the flag --enable-tests
```

Ok... so it tells me to run `cabal configure --enable-tests`. And here's the output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring yesodtry-0.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
hspec -any, yesod-test ==1.2.*
```

I see this line in `yesodtry.cabal`, for the `build-depends` of the `test-suite test` "section":

```
yesod-test >= 1.2 && < 1.3
```

It seems like cabal is not installing the dependencies here. How do I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer on this [Haskell-cafe thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haskell-cafe/SFoNwaq8wdc).

We have to do:

```
cabal configure --enable-tests
cabal install --only-dependencies --enable-tests
```

And the dependencies for the `test-suite test` section will be installed.

I then ran `yesod test`, and here's the last few lines of the output:

```
Linking dist/build/test/test ...
Building yesodtry-0.0.0...
Preprocessing library yesodtry-0.0.0...
In-place registering yesodtry-0.0.0...
Preprocessing test suite 'test' for yesodtry-0.0.0...
Linking dist/build/test/test ...
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test: RUNNING...
Test suite test: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/yesodtry-0.0.0-test.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

Hopefully this will help anyone who encounters the same problem in the future.